# How to make Makefile Variables persist between commands

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is a sample makefile that demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
PLATFORM=wrongName

debug:
    @echo debug $(PLATFORM)

debug-android: android debug

android:PLATFORM=android
android:
    @echo set PLATFORM to $(PLATFORM)
```

here is the terminal output:

```bash
user:~/Project/maketest$ make debug-android
set PLATFORM to android
debug wrongName
```

when calling the target `make debug-android` my intention is to set the PLATFORM variable to "android", and that works in the `android:` command, however the "PLATFORM" var reverts to "wrongName" default value set at the top of the makefile. I'm trying to replace the value here so that any subsequent dependencies for the target will also see the value of "PLATFORM" as "android".
so my question is: how do i make "PLATFORM" variable assignment persist between commands/targets?

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not sure that I follow what you're saying. Can you make a clearer, perhaps actionable, comment?

Comment: @DevSolar I've updated the question. Also i'm not sure what you mean by 
>Your Makefile code does not generate the output you've posted<
when i copy/pasted exactly what the you see in the snippets above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, but you still haven't made clear exactly what you want these rules to do, conceptually.

Here is one way:

```
debug-android:PLATFORM=android
debug-android: android debug

android:
    @echo set PLATFORM to $(PLATFORM)
```

**EDIT:**

Ah, so the idea is to avoid repetition of `PLATFORM=android`. Try this:

```
PLATFORM=wrongName

all: debug-android prod-android test-android

debug:
    @echo Debug $(PLATFORM)

prod:
    @echo Prod $(PLATFORM)

test:
    @echo Test $(PLATFORM)

%-android: PLATFORM=android

debug-android: debug
test-android: test
prod-android: prod
```

If this is on the right track, we can go farther, removing the redundancy of those last three lines.

Comment: the intent behind what I was trying to do is have a single source that sets the PLATFORM, which was the reason behind the `android:` target. so that i wouldn't have to add multiple lines for the same thing (ie. if I wanted a target called `prod-android: android prod` or `test-android: android test` I would have to add additional commands `prod-android: PLATFORM=android` and `test-android:PLATFORM=android`. I can do that, I was just hoping to avoid that kind of unnecessary verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea to do this.  Most of the time if you want to do it, it probably means that you should be thinking about the problem differently.

However, it is possible to do this (in GNU make only) using `eval`.  Usually when I see `eval` used in a recipe it's a code smell but it does work:

```
android:
        $(eval PLATFORM := $(PLATFORM))
        @echo set PLATFORM to $(PLATFORM)
```

Comment: that works exactly as I was hoped it would

Comment: If you want to update with the solution you went with it's better to modify your question with what you ended up doing, rather than edit the answer.  IMO.

Comment: The reason eval is not great is threefold: first, what do you get if someone runs plain `make debug`?  And second, this kind of "action at a distance" is very hard for someone to understand when they are reading makefiles; it's hard to understand the makefile and see where things happen.  And finally, this style perpetuates the incorrect belief that makefile syntax is like a procedural language and targets are like functions, which is really not right and can lead to confusion in other ways.

Comment: So this answer works best, but there is an issue in that the `eval` function sets the PLATFORM var in the <shell> scope, not the <makefile> scope. Provided that it's being read from a shell command all is good, but any makefile target that performs a conditional operation on PLATFORM will see the default value.

Comment: That is not true.  The `eval` function always sets makefile variables, not shell variables.   The reason you have "conditional operations" seeing the old values is that make conditions are parsed when the makefile is read in.  The value won't be set until later, when the recipe is invoked.